# Is it possible to use string substitution variables within the Default VM Arguments of an installed JRE in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse Luna, the dialog that comes up when I go to `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Edit` makes it look like I should be able to use string substitution variables within the Default VM Arguments box, but if I try to do so, the arguments seem to be improperly parsed. Is this just a bug or am I misunderstanding something?

For example, if I have the following in the Default VM Arguments:
`-Xmx8000m ${JRE_PARAMS}`

And the value for JRE_PARAMS in the String Substitutions window is:
`-DtestEmailAddress=person@company.com -Dservice.url=http://machine:8091/some/service`

When the JVM launches and I call `System.getProperty("testEmailAddress")`, the value that comes back is `person@company.com -Dservice.url=http://machine:8091/some/service` and (not surprisingly) there's no property entry for `service.url`.

Update: while the [answer given by copeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30378783/33836) below may work in Juno on Windows, it doesn't appear to work in Luna on a Mac. Anyone know how to escape the slashes on a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

In the String Substitution window, surround each parameter with quotes:

```
"-DtestEmailAddress=person@company.com" "-Danother.property=val2"
```

Works in Eclipse Juno

Comment: That seemed to work for the email address property, but not when the value is a URL - it garbles it into `"-Dservice.url=http:..machine:8091.some.service"`. I've changed the question to include a property with a URL value to reflect that. Any guesses?

Comment: The URL works fine for me in Juno when using quotes: `System.getProperty("service.url")` returns `http://machine:8091/some/service` (tested by printing property value to command line). Also tried other URLS with similar success.

Comment: It would appear to either be a regression in Luna or a potential platform difference. What OS are you using? I'm on a Mac. Given that the characters being garbled are slashes, it could be that Eclipse is trying to parse the text as a path instead of just passing it through as a string.

Comment: Windows. Don't have my Mac handy right now to check, but have you tried escaping the slashes eg `http:\/\/`?

Comment: Sadly, yes. It resulted in the following error message: `Error: Could not find or load main class "-DtestEmailAddress=person@company.com" "-Dservice.url=http:\.\.machine:8091\.some\.service"`